# Importing both specific class and whole package at the same time, which one will Java prefer?

Tags: java

Suppose I have a class in which I want to take the input by using Scanner:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;

public class Test
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      System.out.print("Enter a int: ");
      int input = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
      System.out.println("You've entered: " +input);
   }

}
```

In above program I have used **two** import statements at a time:

(1) With fully qualified class name

(2) With import whole items in package util.

Now my question is:

(1) Which statement the Java compiler will prefer to use since both of import statements produces almost similar meaning in above context.

(2) What mechanism will decide which import statement to prefer, how and why?

*P.S:
I know using above methodology is an ugly way of writing code and we're hardly gonna experience that in real life but it's good to know about the internal working of java in such scenarios.*

Comment: Why do you think one (or the other) is *preferred*? They're the same. Also, imports are for the programmer (Java itself doesn't use them in bytecode).

Comment: You can also import `java.util.Scanner` several times. Nothing changes, except if the compiler could think it would probably wonder if you're all right in the head.

Comment: 1) None is preferred by the compiler. The compiler will only read the import statements line by line as they appear in your file and resolve them one by one. 2) None...

Comment: A better example might have been, “If I have both `import java.util.List;` and `import java.awt.*;`, which List class will the compiler use?”  The answer is, you get a compiler error because the class name is ambiguous.